# How to set dynamically value for key inside nested object in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm setting up JSON object for post,I need to set the nested object values for a key dynamically.How is possible using Angular2/Typescript.

I try to get the values from json and set it dynamically by repatitive function call.Possibly recursion will do the trick,Can someone help me how to write recursion for this function.

```
let encounterPayLoad = {  
      patient:this.orderEncounter.patient.uuid,
      visit:this.orderEncounter.visit.uuid,
      encounterType:this.orderEncounter.encounterType.uuid,
      obs:[  
         {  
            groupMembers:[  
               {  
                  concept:val,//setting concept values as dynamically
                  value:"1000"
               },
         }
      ],
      orders:[  
      ],
      encounterProviders:[  
         {  
          provider: this.appConstants.defaultProviderUUID,
          encounterRole: this.appConstants.defaultEncounterRoleUUID
         }
      ]
   }
   this.groupMember.push(encounterPayLoad);
   console.log("@payLoad",this.groupMember);
  }
```

I want the final object in the below shape.Currently its work at only one level inside groupMembers.

```
{  
   "patient":"e56faafe-70e2-422d-a260-a1c69e72a54c",
   "visit":"7848a99a-323b-4873-9711-2b5f27be86f9",
   "encounterType":"7c179057-ae3d-44d8-b9e7-f5e514992f41",
   "obs":[  
      {  
         "groupMembers":[  
            {  
               "concept":"4876e25c-f580-4a84-9357-a283de220b44",
               "value":"1000"
            },
            {  
               "concept":"964f1f1e-7c26-4e59-bb23-692a4ae02c6f",
               "value":"2000"
            },
            {  
               "concept":"02f962f7-c864-474e-a63a-56feed2ad2dc",
               "value":"3000"
            }
         ],
         "concept":"745449b2-c0e6-4f23-8428-942499142533",
         "order":"0472a6fe-63c5-40f9-b761-dbfa6f91e117"
      }
   ],
   "orders":[  

   ],
   "encounterProviders":[  
      {  
         "provider":"f9badd80-ab76-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66",
         "encounterRole":"240b26f9-dd88-4172-823d-4a8bfeb7841f"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string that you want to generate is called a UUID. You can find functions online to generate it for you in JavaScript.

Here's a similar function, courtesy [JavaScript: Function to create a UUID identifier](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-23.php):

```
private create_UUID() {
  var dt = new Date().getTime();
  var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  return uuid;
}
```

You can then call it in your code like this:

```
let encounterPayLoad = {
  patient: this.orderEncounter.patient.uuid,
  visit: this.orderEncounter.visit.uuid,
  encounterType: this.orderEncounter.encounterType.uuid,
  obs: [{
      groupMembers: [{
          concept: this.create_UUID(),
          value: "1000"
        },
      }
    ],
    orders: [],
    encounterProviders: [{
      provider: this.appConstants.defaultProviderUUID,
      encounterRole: this.appConstants.defaultEncounterRoleUUID
    }]
  }
  this.groupMember.push(encounterPayLoad);
  console.log("@payLoad", this.groupMember);
}
```

Comment: I want to set the concept value as dynamically.

Comment: @MohammadNaveed, fixed.

Comment: thanks,but I need to set the  specific uuid,which I'm getting back from the server.there values can be anything but uuid must be set from server.

Comment: this.conceptService.getConceptSetMembers(this.dataForEncounter[0].order.concept.uuid).subscribe(setMembers=>{
        this.conceptSetMember=setMembers;
        console.log("gettingUUID from server",this.conceptSetMember);
      if(this.conceptSetMember.length>1){
        this.conceptSetMember.forEach(element => {
          this.saveEncounter(element.uuid);
        });
      }  
      });